# NodeJS server can only be requested from cURL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I ran into a *very* odd issue today. I am working on a nodejs server, and I've gotten it working. However, it only works with cURL. I cannot connect to the web page from my browser.

Here's the code I'm using to create the server. "Server is running ..." is logged into the console, and when an http request is made from cURL, it prints *Hello World* into the console.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://acvsapps.med.uottawa.ca');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');    
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, 'xx.xx.xx.xxx');
console.log('Server running at http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/');
```

Unfortunately, from a browser (Google Chrome) it shows this: [image]
.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: And, you're saying that the exact same URL from the exact same computer and the exact same login works from cURL?  That seems unlikely.  Something must be different between the browser request and the cURL request.

Comment: Hi, I just tried your code on my local system, and its work fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually, the problem may be that it can only be requested from the host itself. I tried it with wget and it worked, but it still doesn't work in my browser on my computer.

Comment: Can you ping and traceroute that IP address from your computer.  This sounds like a routing/IP address issue that isn't letting you access that IP address from your computer.  What is the exact URL you're using from cURL and from the browser?

Comment: @jfriend00 I can connect to other places on the host, just not with that port. I'm using `curl http://45.55.71.134:8080/`

Comment: Does `cURL http://45.55.71.134:8080/` work from your computer?  Is there any sort of proxy or firewall between you and the server host?

Comment: No, it doesn't work from my computer either.

Comment: My friend tried it as well and it didn't load for him either

Comment: More information: `http://45.55.71.134:8080/` from my browser returns a 404 page with "Cannot GET /" and an "X-Powered-By: Express" header.